# Sitecore Index Rebuild, Deletes exiting index files

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I am working with Sitecore 7 search, I am rebuilding index in code, I have created an Agent for that, things are working, index rebuild takes 15 seconds, I noticed while index is rebuilding I can't search any content, search gives me 0 results, I think index files are removed from index folder when index is rebuilt, is that right? How can I rebuild index without deleting existing index files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, when a rebuild is issued then the existing index is dropped. To avoid this, you need to change the index type from the default `LuceneIndex` to a `SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex`

`<index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">`

..to..

`<index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">`

This will create a secondary index folder in which the rebuild will take place. When the re-index is complete it will swap the two index folders so that you do not see any downtime of your searches.

There is an equivalent version for the Solr provider as well.

You can see blog posts: [HERE](http://sitecoreunleashed.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/hot-swappable-indexes-with-sitecore-7.html) or [HERE](http://www.sitecore.net/deutsch/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Rebuild-Lucene-Indexes-in-Temporary-Subdirectories.aspx) for a little more information.

Comment: after all this configuration I can see "_sec" folders but when the content of these folders will be swapped with original folders? I can't see any new file created or updated in original folder.

Comment: I am not using web index, I have created 3 indexes for my web site, I have done changes in all 3, Do I need to make these changes in master, core and web? Second article references the changes in web.config file while first article points the changes in indexing config file.